# Programmatically add node in AEM?

Tags: java, service, aem

I need to create a node in AEM using java services. I created a workflow, in which a process triggers a java service inside `content/dam/Test`.

Do I need to create a node using java services or simply create a node programatically?

Comment: AFAIK AEM uses [JCR API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_repository_API_for_Java), so it should be enough to read its [Javadoc](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/index.html?overview-summary.html) and apply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving Data in JCR Node, what am I doing wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828484/saving-data-in-jcr-node-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various APIs which can be used to create a node : 
1. Using **Node API**

- Adapt the resource to Node
  `Node node = resource.adaptTo(Node.class);`
- then add a node using function "addNode(java.lang.String relPath,                    java.lang.String primaryNodeTypeName)"
  `node.addNode(nodeName, NodePrimaryType);`
- you can add properties using function "setProperty(java.lang.String name,Value value)"
- Save the session so that the new Node and its properties are saved

---

2. Using **JcrUtil**
   There are 2 APIs for JCRUtil :

   - One of Apache Jackrabbit 2.0 - [JcrUtils](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.8/org/apache/jackrabbit/commons/JcrUtils.html)
   - And the other Utility for common JCR tasks - [JcrUtil](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/jcr/JcrUtil.html)

You can go through any of them to create a new node.

Answer (score 1):

The workflow session can be adapted to a JCR session, from there you have access to read/write via the [JCR API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/javax.jcr/javadocs/jcr-2.0/index.html).

```
import com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowException;
import com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowSession;
import com.adobe.granite.workflow.exec.WorkItem;
import com.adobe.granite.workflow.exec.WorkflowProcess;
import com.adobe.granite.workflow.metadata.MetaDataMap;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.osgi.framework.Constants;

import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.Session;

@Component
@Service
@Properties({@Property(name = Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION, value = "Some Service")})
public class AddTheNodeWorkflow implements WorkflowProcess {

    @Override
    public final void execute(WorkItem workItem, WorkflowSession workflowSession, MetaDataMap args) throws WorkflowException {
        try {
            final String payloadPath = getPayloadPath(workItem);
            final Session session = workflowSession.adaptTo(Session.class);

            // get the node for the workflow payload
            final Node payloadNode = session.getNode(payloadPath);

            // add the node
            final Node somenode = payloadNode.addNode("somenode");
            somenode.setProperty("myproperty", "my property value");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getPayloadPath(WorkItem workItem) {
        return workItem.getWorkflowData().getPayload().toString();
    }
}
```